My function does not close the WebSocket connection
I have a websocket client which connects to a real time data stream. The connection works fine and when I run hello it connects to the stream. Since the WebSocket server runs and sends permanently there is to much data in a really short time and I want to close the connection manually. I wrote the function close_connection but nothing happens when I call it and I do not know why.
This is what my code looks like:
import websockets
from websockets.sync.client import connect

URL = "wss://test.com/test"
AUTHENTIFICATION = {'Authorization': 'Basic someToken'}
def hello():
    with connect(URL, 
                 additional_headers = AUTHENTIFICATION) as websocket:
        message = websocket.recv()
        resp = websocket.response.status_code
        if websocket.response.status_code == 101:
            print('Connection successful')
        else: 
            print('Failure')
        for message in websocket:
            print(f"Received: {message}")

def close_connection():
    with connect(URL, 
                additional_headers=AUTHENTIFICATION) as websocket:
        websocket.close()


It looks like you're creating a new WebSocket in the close_connection method and then closing it, instead of closing the one you're making in the hello function.

@SarthakKhandelwal you know how I can change that?

If you look here, you can see that as soon as you exit
with connect(URL, additional_headers = AUTHENTIFICATION) as websocket:
your websocket connection is closed by itself. You can need a way to store that websocket and then handle it the way you want. You can look at some patterns given by the websocket library itself and choose one of those.

Now I understand. But what I still not understand is this: I want to build a app with Qt for Python where a map is visible. I want to place a button there with „show live data“ where the WebSocket connects. Do I have to close the app every time when Iwant to disconnect the WebSocket and close the live data? Because of this I had an idea with the „disconnect“ button.

No no, you don't have to close the app. Just store the connection object and pass it around. Did you get a chance to see the patterns link? Can you share more details of your code structure, maybe I can help then
